# Cherry pick all changes from a feature branch to a hotfix branch

Tags: git, merge, version-control

I've gotten myself into a predicament with git.

The setup is as follows:

[image]

We have master, stage and feature branches. We are using merge strategy, without squash.
We were implementing multiple features simultaneously and merging them to the stage branch. Every couple of day we are merging everything to master and deploying to production.

---

But there was a problem on production and we had to revert out changes on master. So right now master does not have any changes that were included in the latest merge from stage.

Our current approach is to:

1. create a hotfix branch for each feature
2. cherry pick commits from original feature branch
3. merge it to master directly.

And I have a problem with one long-standing branch (don't ask how we got here). Basically there was a branch with bunch of commits that were created in a span of couple of weeks (but mostly in one week). Now I'm trying to figure out how can I cherry pick this commits to the hotfix branch. But the thing is that this feature branch also includes merge commits from stage. So it is all messed up.

---

I tried couple of things. I know hash of the first and the last commit on that feature branch. So I tried doing something like this:

`git cherry-pick <hash-first>^..<hash-last>`

But it does not work. It seems it is trying to apply unrelated commit (my guess it is because merges from stage to feature branch). And after resolving a conflict it adds just a single commit with unrelated change. I have no idea what is happening.

---

I also tried just providing a name of a branch:

`git cherry-pick ..<branch_name>`

But it is saying `error: empty commit set passed`
I tried to investigate that

---

I tried rebasing the copy of my feature branch onto the master branch. So I've checkout the feature branch, made new branch out of it and tried to rebase it onto the master. But it seems it does nothing.

---

The only idea I have now it to go through each commit at a time and cherry pick it. But it will create huge about of work and resolving merge conflicts. And potentially it will create differences between stage and master. Is there a better way?

I'm on Linux (using WSL).

Comment: This looks awfully like a rebase without the merges?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by that

Comment: When I'm dealing with a tricky cherry-pick sequence (or rebase) I cherry-pick one commit at a time.

Comment: Try ` git checkout <commit before the bad merge on master>; git checkout -b temp`. Then try to apply some cherry-picks. See if you get different results. [Reverting a merge commit has non-trivial consequences](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the

- first black commit dot on the `feature` branch can be named as `F1`.
- last black commit dot before the merge to `stage` can be named `F9`.
- red revert commit dot on `main` can be named `M3`.
- grey commits on `stage` is `S1`, `S2` and `S3`.

then you can reintroduce all the commits from `feature` into `main` (aka "branch with cherry-picks") by running

```bash
git branch reintroduce_feature_commits F9
git rebase --onto M3 F1^ reintroduce_feature_commits
```

(you can alternatively use `--onto main` instead of `--onto M3`)

`F1^` means the parent of `F1` because the rebase syntax is `--onto <target_commit> <start_commit_NOT_including> <branch_to_rebase>`.

---

The above rebase will basically be the same as cherry-pick F1 to F9 as well as the cherry-pick S1 to S3 because by default rebase flattens the version history. You can also use the `--rebase-merges`<sup>1</sup> option to "preserve" the merge commits from `stage` in your rebase.

I put preserve in quotes there because will not preserve as in re-using the original merge commits, it will create new, rebased ones. But the merge structure should stay the same (although if there were conflicts in the merge that were resolved manually in the original merge they needs to be resolved manually again (yet another reason to prefer rebase over merge because then that problem never arises)).

The potential conflicts related to the merges above will of course appear in a pure cherry-pick approach as well, so if you get conflicts you get conflicts one way or the other (although you normally will be much better of getting multiple, smaller conflicts from rebase/cherry-pick rather than one large one from merge).

---

<sup>1</sup>
E.g `git rebase --rebase-merges --onto M3 F1^ reintroduce_feature_commits`

Answer (score 0):

```
git rebase -i --onto=origin/master <hash-first>^..<hash-last>
```

`-i` will take you into interactive mode.

You'll be presented with a list of commits in the given range.

Select and delete the lines of commits that you do **not** want to cherry-pick.

Save and close.

(If the editor shows is "vim", then pressing `dd` will delete a line. Typing `:wq` [enter] will save and quit)